# Параметры которые требуются для однозначного определения сферы / конуса / цилиндра / тора

Tags: геометрия

Сколько параметров требуется для однозначного определения сферы / конуса / цилиндра / тора? Какие параметры?

Comment: Что значит "однозначное определение сферы"? Только форма самой сферы? Или положение этой сферы в пространстве?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что школьная геометрия вряд ли должна входить в тематику сайта

Comment: @AnT, поэтому и задал этот вопрос ибо он мне не понятен

Comment: Ну так, он никому не понятен. Что имелось в виду должно, наверное, быть понятно из контекста. Если же и контекста нет, то что имелось в виду знает только тот, кто формулировал этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

- Сфера - радиус
- Цилиндр/конус - радиус основания, высота
- Тор - радиус
  образующей окружности и расстояние от центра образующей окружности до
  оси вращения.

Ну, и если нужно расположить все это в пространстве, то координаты какой-то точки (центр сферы или тора, центр основания конуса и цилиндра) и, для всех кроме сферы - как-то задать ориентацию в пространстве.